# Map array result in mongodb aggregation

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following MongoDB query:

```
const vaccination = await Schedule.aggregate([
        { $match: { status: ScheduleStatus.Published } },
        { "$unwind": { "path": "$vaccines", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true } },

        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$vaccines.vaccine",
                "count": { "$sum": "$vaccines.stok" },

            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: { from: 'vaccines', localField: '_id', foreignField: '_id', as: 'vaccine' },
        },
        {
            $project: {

                "count": 1,
                "vaccine": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$vaccine.name", 0] }


            }
        }

    ]);
```

and return the following results :

```
[
    {
        "_id": "61efd8a812432135c08a748d",
        "count": 20,
        "vaccine": "Sinovac"
    }
]
```

is there a way I can make the output to be an array of values like:

```
[["Sinovac",20]]
```

Thanks sorry for my bad english

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: sorry my bad. I forgot to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can't get the exact structure you asked for, by definition the aggregation framework returns an array of "documents", a document is in the form of `{key: value}`, What you can do however is return the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "values": [
      "61efd8a812432135c08a748d",
      20,
      "Sinovac"
    ]
  }
]
```

With this pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      values: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
          },
          as: "item",
          in: "$$item.v"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZHcad3msaDh)

Comment: So if I want to get the result I want, I should map it using the map function in Javascript on the backend?

Comment: this `$map` runs in the database, no need to use map function in javascript, if you want to  not keep the `_id` you can remove the `_id` first (unset or project) and then `$map` like this [example](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6251a540f7e3c64c6511e16d)

Comment: Hey @Tom Slabbaert I made a few edits to the aggregate (I moved your _id: 0 to a project above):




db.collection.aggregate([
 {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
},
},
  {
    $project: {
      values: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
          },
          as: "item",
          in: "$$item.v"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

This removes the _id from the array